# Disable auto-reloading of the configuration file

Tags: activemq-artemis

I create/delete most of the Artemis objects through `Controls`, so I don't need to automatically reload the config file.

Is there a way to disable auto-reloading of the configuration file?

In the `Configuration Reload` documentation section, I did not find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to *explicitly* disable reloading the configuration file (although this would be an easy feature to implement). However, the refresh period is a Java `Long` so you can use a huge value up to [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) (i.e. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) to ensure reloading never actually happens.

I created [ARTEMIS-3166](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3166) to provide a way to explicitly disable configuration reload in a future release.